# Spark: Read all lines after a delimiter in a text file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 10000 text files in a directory and need to keep the content from the line with a specific String ("Content") until end of file. How can I do this in spark?
I am trying to read all files with wholeTextFiles and then map and filter values.

I need only "Content" part of each file

```
        From :  SIDE A
        To :  SIDE B
        Date : 9999.99
               March 03
=>      Content :
        ----------------------------------------
                Content starts from here            
                and continues until last line 
                of each file.
```

Comment: wholeTextFiles looks like a decent choice? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Are each of the text files small enough to keep in memory (a few MBs, assuming you don't have a special machine)?

Comment: I don't know how to filter first 6 lines here and read "Content" part of each file. files are 4 KB each.

Comment: it does not answer exactly your question but could you rewrite your files on a shell ? if you run somthing like "tail -n +7 file1 > newfile1", even for 10000 it should only take a few minutes